# Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 250000, 31

Tags: r

I have a dataset of locations and dates.I have to plot a bar graph of locations across dates. I tried the code below  but got above error:argunets imply differing number of rows.my dataset contains around 25000 rows of data and 15 columns.will you help me with ploting a bar graph ??

I have tried this code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(database)) {

    if(input$n1==as.integer(unique(sub(".*/.*/","",database$pickup_date[i]))) &&
     input$n2==as.integer((unique(sub("/.*/.*","",database$pickup_date[i]))))) {
    date_var<-sub("/2.*","",database$pickup_date[i])
    date_var<-sub("*./","",date_var)
    #print(date_var)
    #list<-unique(list(database$Pickup_name))
    #list
    count=count+1
    name[count]<-as.list(sub(database$Pickup_name[i]))

  }
  df1<-data.frame(name,date_array)
  bp1<-barplot(df1$name,names.arg = df1$date_array)
  }
 read.table(text='pickup_location   pickup_name
```

3/14/2016   mumbai
6/12/2016   mumbai
1/19/2016   mumbai
4/6/2016    mumbai
3/26/2016   mumbai
1/30/2016   mumbai
6/17/2016   mumbai
5/21/2016   mumbai
5/27/2016   mumbai
3/10/2016   mumbai
5/10/2016   mumbai
5/15/2016   mumbai
2/19/2016   mumbai
6/1/2016    mumbai
5/27/2016   pune
5/16/2016   pune
4/11/2016   pune
4/14/2016   pune
6/27/2016   pune
6/5/2016    pune
2/28/2016   pune
4/1/2016    pune
4/9/2016    pune
6/25/2016   nashik
6/3/2016    nashik
2/14/2016   nashik
2/27/2016   nashik
6/20/2016   nashik
6/13/2016   nashik
3/23/2016   nashik
5/17/2016   nashik
5/21/2016   nashik
5/10/2016   nashik
4/17/2016   nashik
')

Comment: Perhaps `name[[count]] <- ...` instead of `name[count] <- ...`? Generally it's best to include a reproducible & minimal example including sample data and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: `sub` is vectorized .  You don't need a loop.  Also, the `sub(database$Pickup_name[i]))` is without a pattern

Comment: Can you help me with ploting a bargraph of location across dates.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example as the other commenter requested

Comment: pickup_date Pickup_name
3/14/2016 mumbai
6/12/2016 mumbai
1/19/2016 mumbai
3/26/2016 mumbai
1/30/2016 mumbai
6/17/2016 mumbai
5/21/2016 mumbai
5/27/2016 mumbai
3/10/2016 mumbai
5/10/2016 mumbai
5/27/2016 pune
5/16/2016 pune
4/14/2016 pune
6/27/2016 pune
2/28/2016 pune
6/25/2016 pune
6/13/2016 nashik
3/23/2016 nashik
5/17/2016 nashik
5/21/2016 nashik
5/10/2016 nashik
4/17/2016 nashik
6/23/2016 nashik
5/27/2016 nashik

Comment: No data in comments, please, just edit the question and insert it there. One question per question, please. If you've resolved the issue with *"differing number of rows"*, then self-answer or just close/delete this question. Your request for plotting should really be a new question.

Comment: can you help me for attaching a file or sending you the data

Comment: There are some good examples at: [reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), namely with `dput(head(x,n=10))` (or whatever size and/or selection of rows provides a complete example). Alternatively, just include a literal `read.table(text='...')` or `data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),...)` building command.